# My wordpress posts wont get indexed/displayed anymore in Google image search

Tags: google-search-console, htaccess, google-index, yoast

Suddenly my website seems to be locked out of Google image search.

None of the articles of the website get indexed when I search, however search console says the urls are getting crawled.

I have installed the following plugins on my WordPress website and the problems came after the installation and usage of the following plugins.

- Headers Security Advanced & HSTS WP  (setting security headers standard settings)
- WP optimize combine JS and CSS (combine css files / js )
- Smush (smushed images)

I think my .htaccess got corrupted somehow. Also in search console when I test my homepage it says:

Page Resources unable to load 71/106.
These are all scripts and css files, and also images. The site screenshot seems to be completely different, it says it tests with  Googlebot (smartphone)

What I did so far:

1. I have deactivated the plugin smush and made sure the image URLs also are set back as original.
2. Headers Security Advanced & HSTS WP and WP optimize combine JS and CSS Disabled
3. Disabled WP optimize so the js/css files are not combined anymore
4. I let Wordfence generate a new .htaccess file in case it was corrupted
5. Updated permalinks and cleared cache
6. Live test URL homepage and submit to Google to validate

**Does anyone have a suggestion on what I can do? Or what may cause the error?**

Because at this point my website articles are not getting displayed in visual appearance in Google search results.
The website is working as it should (the scripts on the site all are 200 responses) the indexing problem is huge, also the errors in crawled test page remain as it cannot load the scripts so google crawler bot says.

Robot.txt file should be okay this is the content:

```
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Sitemap: https://www.mywebsite.nl/sitemap_index.xml
```

Note: I have WordPress YOAST plugin installed which includes an image sitemap as per post and or page.

Does anyone have a suggestion what to do? At this point I am clueless and Google won't index my images while it says the site is getting indexed.

Comment: What is "visual search"?  Do you mean Google image search?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I edited the post title.

Comment: [Images not being shown in Google Image Search after redesign - Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/99533/images-not-being-shown-in-google-image-search-after-redesign) recommends doing a crawl of your own site to test whether or not your images can be fetched by a bot correctly.

Comment: [How do I get Images for my site to Return in Google Searches](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1000/how-do-i-get-images-for-my-site-to-return-in-google-searches) suggests creating an image sitemap which would give you better visibility into image indexing in Google Search Console.

Comment: Forgot to mention I use YOAST SEO plugin, The developers say this about image sitemap: 
"We don’t generate a separate image sitemap in our plugin. We follow Google’s advice and include them in the page or post sitemaps. For example, if you take a look at your post sitemap, you’ll see Images column under which image counts is visible (if images exist in that post).
The images are not visible in the user interface but they are added to the source code of the sitemap, where search engines can see them and crawl them."

Source:  https://wordpress.org/support/topic/image-sitemap-with-yoast-seo/

Comment: How can you not know if your htaccess is corrupted ?